# VScode deleting itself

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a problem where my VSCode keeps deleting itself after I do anything on it. e.g. when I code in Latex or just using it as a text editor, the entire code.exe itself keeps deleting itself. I have been downloading the latest version from the website itself but it still does the same thing with deleting itself.

PS. When I say deleting itself, I meant the entire VSCode uninstalls itself.

Thanks.

Comment: Just had the same thing happen - weird :S

Comment: happened to me yesterday after installing docker desktop

Comment: Happened to me also... shut down the pc and it was gone.

Comment: This has happened quite a few times with me.

Comment: This just happened to me in the last week.

Comment: Aaand its still happening.... They've locked the issue on github.

Comment: Happened to me on Mac

Comment: it happened to me it is a fresh question. i shut down windows 10 while vs code running.

Comment: It happened to me today, on Windows 11...

Comment: It happened to me twice this week. Today is the 3rd time I am installing it. I also saw they locked the issue on Github. This is sad since I use VS Code all day every day.

Comment: mee too!!! it shows the dialog asking to uninstall vs Code.

Comment: This is still happening. 4 years later ! Such a pain really

Answer (score 2):

There are several steps to kinda fix this:

1. First run troubleshooter.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRdXI.png
2. If the problem continues, uninstall using unins000.exe in the folder where you installed vscode, and reinstall it.
3. If you use insiders build, kindle use the standard or non-insiders version.
4. If the problem still continues, check for updates in your pc and make sure you have updated your pc to the latest.

It should work after this, if not kindle contact the vscode support through get help app or your pc's manufacturer's support team.

Hope this helps in your wonderful coding journey!!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this problem is caused by antivirus, especially smaDav.
Vs-Code normally updates itself in the background, so when the antivirus catches it trying to execute code with administrator permission, the antivirus will automatically block and delete the vs-code entire folder,

**THE SOLUTION IS:**
you need to install the vs-code again, this time turn off the auto-update

Comment: don't uninstall the old one, just download vscode and install, After installing, open it go to settings,  search "updatew",  you will see something like  "Update: Enable Windows Background Updates", Just untick it, that's all